# What does return -1 do in java?

Tags: java

So for example, if searching for an element in a list and you return -1 it seems that the element can't be found. But why -1? What's the difference between returning 0, 1, & -1.

Comment: Because the first element's index is `0`. `-1` is clearly out of range.

Comment: by definition, the indices of arrays and list start from `0` so a negative number is out of that valid range, indicating nothing has been found. There exists method which return other negative numbers, like `Arrays.binarySearch()`

Comment: Put the question differently - you search for an element in a list and return `1` when not found. Why might that be a problem?

Comment: minus one would not be a valid index of an array or list. It could also be any negative number

Comment: To be fair, you could return `list.size()` to indicate an item not found, as that is also an invalid list index. It wouldn't be an unreasonable follow-up question as to why you would use -1 over that (suggested reasons: more verbose to test, more computationally expensive to test (if the list has a poor size implementation), may "become" a valid index if the list grows...).

Comment: @AndyTurner it is consistent to how indexes work. So while not obligatory, when you are implementing such a logic  in many cases you are somewhat urged by pre- and postconditions for indexes to use -1. (eg. get the substring for an index, with -1 it works consistently and so on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the method returns -1 it means that what you were searching was not found. Instead, if you get a positive number then that's the index of the element that you were searching in the array.